# When use declare "year" in WP taxonomy, the site has issue of page rendering

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

At theme folder functions.php, after putting custom taxonomy "year" declaration by using following code:
`register_taxonomy('year', 'post');`

The WP website page is not rendering properly, it will always lands to default blog listing page while the permalink is set to use "Post name"

The WP website page should land to page respectively.